# Facebook Api to get any user profile pic by giving the facebook user_id

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am taking "user_id" as input and passing to my Js function which suppose to give me the profile photo data.I am trying to show that photo.Logged in user profile picture is showing properly. But when I pass logged out user_id, getting error and it says "TypeError: response.picture is undefined". It is the first time, I am trying to use fb api to get user info only by user_id.Here is my function."a" is coming from my input.

```
// without login,just giving username and getting profile picture
    function getInfopeople(a) {

        //https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture  /me/picture?redirect=false&height=300' //this part is not working

        var user_id = "/"+a + "/picture";

        console.log(user_id);
        FB.api('/http://graph.facebook.com/user_id,','GET', {fields:'picture.width(150).height(150)'}, function(response) {
            document.getElementById('user_status').innerHTML = "<img src='" + response.picture.data.url + "'>";
        });
    }
```

Comment: you are not supposed to get the id (or anything else) of users who did not authorize your app, so how did you get the id?

Comment: id is coming for the input form. Anyways, I solved it. Thank you for your co-operation.: )

Answer (score 1):

You were making incorrect API call. You should call this API to fetch the user profile picture.

```
function getInfopeople(user_id) {

    // https://graph.facebook.com/{version}/{user_id}?fields=picture.width(150).height(150)

    FB.api('/' + user_id, 'GET', { fields:'picture.width(150).height(150)' }, function(response) {
        document.getElementById('user_status').innerHTML = "<img src='" + response.picture.data.url + "'>";
    });
}
```

Comment: Yah. That was the problem. I figured it out later. Thank you for understanding my problem. Thank You so much for clearing it. :)